# Can't understand this for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I know this is super basic here but can someone explain why this pushes out 31?

```js
var x = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  x += 5 * i;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: What did you expect it would push out?

Comment: Cause `1 + 5 + 10 + 15` is `31` .. ;)

Comment: The loop iterates through the values of `i` for 0, 1, 2, and 3. So, `x += 5 * i;` adds the values 0, 5, 10, and 15 to `x`, which started at 1. Add them up and you get 31.

Comment: Great time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Before the loop starts, x is 1.

Zeroth iteration: i is 0, 5 * 0 (0) is added to x. x becomes 1.

First iteration: i is 1, 5 * 1 (5) is added to x. x becomes 6.

Second iteration: i is 2, 5 * 2 (10) is added to x. x becomes 16.

Third iteration: i is 3, 5 * 3 (15) is added to x. x becomes 31.

There is no fourth iteration, because the for loop only runs while `i<4`.

Answer (score 1):

The operator `+=` adds to the variable `x` the sum of itself + another value.

`x += 1` **is equals to** `x = x + 1`

**So, that loop executes the following:**

```
x = 1          = 1     <---- Initialization
x = 1  + 5 * 0 = 1     <---- Iteration 0
x = 1  + 5 * 1 = 6     <---- Iteration 1
x = 6  + 5 * 2 = 16    <---- Iteration 2
x = 16 + 5 * 3 = 31    <---- Iteration 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, check this out:

```js
var x = 1; // X= 1
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  // the below is actually x = (5 * i) + x;
  x += 5 * i;
  // LOG THE OUTPUT
  console.log("At step " + i + ", X is = " + x);
}
console.log("Total: " + x);

// Want more? Here:
/*
 At step 0, X = (5 * 0) + 1 => 1
 At step 1, X = (5 * 1) + 1 => 5 + 1 => 6
 At step 2, X = (5 * 2) + 6 => 10+16 => 16
 At step 3, X = (5 * 3) + 16 => 15 + 16 => 31
*/
```